# How do i get Physical Address of a mac os x device by using c#

Tags: c#, cocoa, visual-studio-mac

I am using visual studio for mac using c#. I have tried  system.net.networkinformation but it gives me blank string.

```
foreach (NetworkInterface nic in NetworkInterface.GetAllNetworkInterfaces())
            {
                if (nic.OperationalStatus == OperationalStatus.Up)
                {
                    mac += nic.GetPhysicalAddress().ToString();
                    //Console.WriteLine(mac);
                    break;
                }
            }
```

This is what i am using to get mac address. It works fine in windows desktop application but not working in os x. I am trying to get mac address of mac desktop for its unique identification.

Comment: Could you please add some details to your question? In addition please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: hi please check now.

Comment: Are you using `Xamarin.Mac`? If you are trying to get a unique id, use the `IOPlatformUUID` (via I/O Kit) and not a Mac address of an interface as those are easily spoofed.

Comment: No i am using visual studio for mac. Is there any other way uniquely identify device ?

Comment: i got the answer  from https://www.experts-exchange.com/questions/27686162/C-Get-MAC-address-with-Mono-for-Mac-platform.html    here

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Below function gives exact mac addresses which i need.

```
  public static string GetMacAddress()
        {
            System.Net.NetworkInformation.NetworkInterfaceType Type = 0;
            string MacAddress = string.Empty;
            try
            {
                System.Net.NetworkInformation.NetworkInterface[] theNetworkInterfaces = System.Net.NetworkInformation.NetworkInterface.GetAllNetworkInterfaces();
                foreach (System.Net.NetworkInformation.NetworkInterface currentInterface in theNetworkInterfaces)
                {
                    Type = currentInterface.NetworkInterfaceType;
                    if (Type == System.Net.NetworkInformation.NetworkInterfaceType.Ethernet || Type == System.Net.NetworkInformation.NetworkInterfaceType.GigabitEthernet || Type == System.Net.NetworkInformation.NetworkInterfaceType.FastEthernetFx)
                    {
                        MacAddress = currentInterface.GetPhysicalAddress().ToString();
                        break;
                    }
                }

                return MacAddress;

            }
            catch 
            {
                // your code goes here

            }

        }
```